# How to read Json format in flash using AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, json

Hello guys its been a while since im trying to get this working, but im very new at this and i cant get this working good, so this is the problem:

Im very new at AS3 and JSON format, i want to download this file: http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&from=0&to=20&minx=-180&miny=-90&maxx=180&maxy=90&size=medium&mapfilter=true and the retrive the first 5 photos links to my flash application.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib).  Specifically, what you want is the JSON decoder, found in [src/com/adobe/serialization](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/serialization).